# Why does my NI Komplete Audio 6 have very low input volume?

Tags: audio-recording

I have an Audio Technica AT4040 connected to a recently purchased Komplete Audio 6.

I used to use this same microphone with a Digi 003 and Pro Tools and it was always very sensitive... I could hear sounds from across the room in my headphones before. However, with the Komplete Audio 6, there is now hardly any volume. Even with the gain all the way up I get a hiss, but not a whole lot coming through from an instrument or vox (though it is there). It's only really possible to get it to peak by banging directly on the microphone or screaming into it.

The odd thing is, if I turn phantom power off and on for 4 or 5 seconds after it kicks in the volume seems a lot more reasonable allowing it to pick up sounds from across the room like it did before. However, it quickly seems to auto adjust back to the very low volume.

Any idea what causes this and how it can be fixed?

This happens on both my Mac in Garage Band and in Ableton on my Windows machine.

Comment: This seems like a good question for NI tech support.

Comment: Probably is a question for NI tech support, but just for kicks, how is the mic connected?  What audio interface?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's limited to a particular misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same unit and my recording level was low too. I end-up returning the unit got other unit with same issue, nothing that I did was helping to gain the input level end-up buying other brand which works out of the box.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the sloping on your mic and see if that helps. Also, if your mic has a psu attached, don't use phantom power at all. Not sure why you're getting that error as it's not a common problem. I cut the gain on the front of my KA6 up to the half way point and mines produces very high sensitivity. It might just be a mic issue. I have a Sterling audio mic which is comparable in price to your mic and I have no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It became ok after installation of software  **Guitar Rig 5 Elements Selection** via Native Access tool. Now the gain is normal and reaches to red line. The tool has lots of effects, filters, reverb and etc. I did not check with other software programms, but I think you have to adjust in software you use. It's my first sound card and I am so happy with it. So I wish to have a fun with this device ))

Answer (score 0):

The answer from S.O.U.L.1 alludes to this to this but... In my case, the problem is that phantom power on the unit via USB plugged into my laptop is not sufficient.

If I switch to an external phantom power unit and turn it off on the Komplete Audio 6, the volume is as it should be.